# Проблема с загрузкой данных в UICollection из Firebase

Tags: swift, firebase-database, uicollectionview

Проблема заключается в том что фотографии не загружаются в коллекцию.Класс с загрузкой

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import FirebaseDatabase
import FirebaseStorage
import FirebaseAuth
import Firebase
struct Celltest {
    var name:String
    var image:UIImage
}
class MenuCell {
   let ref = Database.database().reference().child("Users")
  
    var cells=[Celltest]()
    init() {
        setUp()
    }
    func setUp(){
        ref.child(Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid).observe(.value) { (snapshot) in
            guard let value=snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "image").value,snapshot.exists()else{
                    return
                }
            
            let references=Storage.storage().reference(forURL: value as! String)
            let megabyte=Int64(1*1024*1024)
            references.getData(maxSize: megabyte) { (data,error) in
                guard let imageData=data else{
                    return
                }
                let image=UIImage(data: imageData)
                guard let values=snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "name").value,snapshot.exists()else{
                    return
                }
                
                let test=Celltest(name: values as! String, image: image!)
                self.cells=[test]
            }
        }
     
    }
}
```

Контроллер ячейки

```
import UIKit

class CollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var productImage: UIImageView!
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }
    func sutUpCell(test:Celltest){
        self.productImage.image=test.image
    }
}
```

ViewController где находится коллекция

```
import UIKit

class CollectionViewController: UIViewController {
    var menu:MenuCell=MenuCell()
    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.collectionView.register(UINib(nibName: "CollectionViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "CollectionViewCell")
        self.collectionView.dataSource=self
        self.collectionView.delegate=self
    }
    
}
extension CollectionViewController:UICollectionViewDataSource,UICollectionViewDelegate{
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return menu.cells.count
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell=collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell
        let test=menu.cells[indexPath.item]
        cell.sutUpCell(test: test)
        collectionView.reloadData()
        return cell
    }
    
    
}
```